# Check if box is selected Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

I have a web element `<div class="check-indicator"/>` and I want to see if this element is checked or not so I searched around the web and found out that I can do

```
boolean condition = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
    ("div[class='check-indicator']")).isSelected();
```

but the condition returns false when the element is checked.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

---

Since the `<div>` tag/element does not return a boolean I instead worked around it by finding the element which contains an `active` substring which indicates that a checkbox is checked (but here the check box is really an image instead of a checkbox which is why I had to do it that way).

Comment: can you post the html code for that element and link to the page if possible.And you can check the attribute of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isSelected()` is only applicable to input elemnts such as checkboxes options in a select, and radio buttons.

you are trying to call it on a `div` which is impossible to ever return `true`.

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.java#L116

**edit**:

Per your comment, it looks like an edge-case, and you'll need to implement something custom.  Looking at your class name, `"check-indicator"` tells me that it is indicating that it **IS** checked.. therefore, merely validating its presence is plenty.

Comment: Thanks, but what if there aren't any select elements nor radio buttons?

Comment: Thanks, I think I know where my problem is now. I will re-edit my question to include the answer.

Comment: Also, I will upvote your answer once I get the required amount of points. Thanks again!